# bower init - difference between amd, es6, globals and node

Tags: node.js, bower, js-amd, ecmascript-6

I am creating my first Bower component. After running `bower init` the script asks me 'what types of modules does this package expose?' with these options:

- amd
- es6
- globals
- node

what is the difference between these options?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

If you don't know, it's quite likely globals is the right answer for you.

Either way, you need to understand:

- [what is and why AMD](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html)
- [what is a nodejs module](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html)
- [what is ecmascript 6 and especially es6 modules](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:modules)

### [UPDATE]

This feature was introduced very recently in bower and is not documented at all yet (AFAIK). It essentially describes the `moduleType`, which states for what module technology the package is meant to be consumed (see above).

Right now, It doesn't have any effect apart from setting the `moduleType` property in the `bower.json` file of the package.

See https://github.com/bower/bower/pull/934 for the original pull-request.

### [UPDATE #2]

A few additional points, to answer comments:

- right now AFAIK there is no validation done on the `moduleType` property - which means that people are technically allowed to use whatever value they want for it, including `angularjs` if they feel inclined to do so
- the [bower committee](https://github.com/bower/bower/pull/1129#issuecomment-37359448) seems to not be keen toward the inclusion of additional `non-interoperable/proprietary moduleTypes` (think composer, angular, etc) - which is easily understandable, but yet again, nothing really prevents people from using the `moduleType` value they want
- an exception to the previous is the (somewhat) recent inclusion of the `yui moduleType`, so, there are "exceptions" to be made, assuming they are [part of a concerted plan](https://github.com/bower/bower/pull/1129#issuecomment-37828996)

What I would do if I were to author a package for a not-listed package manager and publish it on bower?

I would author an es6 module, and use / patch [es6-transpiler](https://github.com/square/es6-module-transpiler) to output the package format I need. Then I would either/and:

- petition the bower guys to include my package technology as a choice (based on the fact it's supported by es6-transpiler as a target)
- publish my package including both the es6 module version of it and the transpiled XXX version of it, and use `es6` as a `moduleType`

Disclaimer: I don't have real-life experience authoring angularjs modules.

Comment: would globals be the right answer for creating an AngularJS module/package?

Comment: I updated my post with additional thoughts about the question "what to do with unsupported package managers" - yet again, this field is not mandatory or used for anything right now - its value is informative only. As for `angularjs` in itself, I might use `globals`, yes, but read my update. Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm using node. Does that mean I am exposing node modules? I am also using angular, which was what I was installing using bower when I noticed that I had a message telling me I had "No bower.json file to save to, use bower init to create one". (Or, if this is a separate question, I can write a question. I thought maybe this was an appropriate comment to put here since it relates to your answer. Thanks!)

Answer (score 27):

### Initial

I'm using `bower init` for first time too.

The options should refer to the different ways to modularize some JavaScript code:

- amd: using AMD `define`, like requirejs.
- node: using Node.js `require`.
- globals: using JavaScript module pattern to expose a global variable (like window.JQuery).
- es6: using upcoming EcmaScript6 module feature.

In my case I wrote a Node.js module [dflow](http://g14n.info/dflow) but I'm using browserify to create a *dist/dflow.js* file that exports a global *dflow* var: so I selected **globals**.

### Other Updates

The command I used to browserify [dflow](http://g14n.info/dflow) as a *window* global object was

`browserify -s dflow -e index.js -o dist/dflow.js`

I changed it cause I prefer to use *require* also inside the browser, so now I am using

`browserify -r ./index.js:dflow -o dist/dflow.js`

and so I changed the *bower.moduleType* to **node** in my *bower.json* file.

The main motivation was that if my module name has a dash, for example my project [flow-view](http://g14n.info/flow-view), I need to *camelize* the global name in *flowView*.

This new approach has two other benefits:

1. Node and browser interface are the same. Using *require* on both client side and server side, let me write only once the code examples, and reuse them easily on both contexts.
2. I use npm scripts and so, I can take advantage of `${npm_package_name}` variable and write once the script I use to browserify.

This is another topic, but, it is really worth that you consider how it is useful the latter benefit: let me share the `npm.scripts.browserify` attribute I use in my *package.json*

`"browserify": "browserify -r ./index.js:${npm_package_name} -o dist/${npm_package_name}.js"`

Comment: you can actually using require inside of define for ex:

`define(function(require, exports, module) {
  "use strict";

  module.exports = {
    Collection: require("./collection"),
    View: require('./view')
  };
});`

Answer (score 7):

Just for reference, this is precisely what bower specifies regarding the module types:

> The type of module defined in the `main` JavaScript file. Can be one or an array of the following strings:
>
> - `globals`: JavaScript module that adds to global namespace, using `window.namespace` or `this.namespace` syntax
> - `amd`: JavaScript module compatible with AMD, like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/), using `define()` syntax
> - `node`: JavaScript module compatible with [node](https://nodejs.org/) and [CommonJS](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html) using `module.exports` syntax
> - `es6`: JavaScript module compatible with [ECMAScript 6 modules](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html), using `export` and `import` syntax
> - `yui`: JavaScript module compatible with [YUI Modules](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/yui/create.html), using `YUI.add()` syntax

Relevant link: https://github.com/bower/spec/blob/master/json.md#moduletype